# Informatica Java transformation to generate output file for each MQ message in Realtime MQ schedule

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to generate FlatFile as output contains MQ message Data which is configured to run in Real time. need help with Java code configuration in Informatica PowerCenter Java transformation. 
Source is MQ message, Target is Flatfile. Schedule is MQ Realtime with Destructive Read option for MQSeries messages and recovery strategy configured.

I am trying below code, but output is not generated.

```
Writer writer = null;

filename_1 = o_File_Name;

try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new         FileOutputStream(o_File_Name), "utf-8"));
writer.write(MESSAGE_DATA);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// Report
} finally 
{
   try {writer.close();
} catch (Exception e)
{/*ignore*/}
}
```

For each M.Q. message it should generate a separate output file which contains message data in it.

Comment: Can you show your mapping? I don't understand the need for Java Transformation. Why not just use a Target Transformation? And - if needed - a Transaction Control?

Comment: Java Transformation is not needed in this case. You should directly route it to Target Flat file. Do you have to any other processing done on java ? If you want to redirect the message to different file, use TC or router to achieve that.

Comment: due to limitations for using Transaction control transformation in realtime MQ mappings it is required to use Java transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Configure below code in Java transformation in "Java Code" tab in "On Input Row" box.

    Writer writer = null;
    //just writing out the filename here so that you can write to your target for     reconciling 

        filename1 = o_File_Name;

    try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream(o_File_Name), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(MESSAGE_DATA);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Report
    } finally {
       try {writer.close();} catch (Exception e) {/*ignore*/}
    }

    under Import Packages table - add below packages.
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;

    pass MESSAGE_DATA as input data which should be content in a file. and pass     o_File_Name as location of your file -- $$TGTPATH\\FLATFILES\\xyz.txt
```